# Find Maximum Number

Tags: arrays, ruby, hashmap

I have two arrays and a truck. I have to find out how many units I can fit in a truck. Here are the arrays:

```
boxes = [3, 1, 6]
units_per_box = [2, 7, 4]
truck_size = 6
```

Each box is the same size and the truck holds that many boxes. What I have to find out is the maximum amount of units that can fit on the truck. Here is what I have so far:

```
array = []
hash = Hash[boxes.zip units_per_box] => {3=>2, 1=>7, 6=>4}
hash.each { |k, v| k.times { array << v } } => [2, 2, 2, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Now, I have to find the maximum number of items in `array` that will fit on the truck. Each number in the array is a box and the truck will hold 6 boxes. Just looking at the numbers, you can see the number should be 27 since 7 + (4 * 5) = 27. How can I figure this out in code? Am I even going in the right direction?

Comment: I am pretty sure there's a more optimized solution, but off the top of my head, I think you can brute-force it using `Array#combination`

Comment: Assuming that units per box directly correlates with the number of boxes and without changing too much of what you have done `boxes.zip(units_per_box).flat_map {|(a,b)| [b]*a}.sort.last(truck_size).sum`. If `units_per_box` is independent of `boxes` then `boxes.sort.zip(units_per_box.sort).flat_map {|(a,b)| [b]*a}.sort.last(truck_size)` might be another option

Comment: Are these box *sizes* or specific boxes that each contain a certain number of units? It seems like an ambiguous question.

Comment: All or none from a box must be loaded. The trucks capacity is full boxes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have multiple red herrings here. First, it doesn't seem to matter how many boxes of each item you have, as the goal is getting the most units in the truck.

Second, the truck size itself doesn't seem to matter. If the previous assumption is correct, then we only care about the units per box and the maximum there will always hold regardless of the truck size.

If all those assumptions are correct, then `units_per_box[1]`, or `7` will be the answer in this situation. Again, it seems like we may need some clarification here. I will delete and/or edit my question as needed.

Comment: The truck holds 6 boxes (this does matter) and since boxes are all the same size. The question really is are "units" all the same size such that in this case a box can clearly hold at least 7 "units" because at least 1 box has 7 units in it.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close -- you have the array of integers, and you want the N largest, right?

That's just:

```rb
fits_in_truck = [2, 2, 2, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4].sort.last(n)
units_in_truct = fits_in_truck.sum
```

As a whole, with some more meaningful names to clarify things:

```rb
num_per_type = [3, 1, 6]
box_unit_types = [2, 7, 4]
truck_size = 6

box_type_tally = box_unit_types.zip(num_per_type).to_h

boxes = box_type_tally.flat_map do |box_units, num_boxes|
  [box_units] * num_boxes
end

loadable_boxes = boxes.sort.last(truck_size)
deliverable_units = loadable_boxes.sum
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Your answer is a longer version of my comment on the OP but the exact same methodology.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand there are given numbers of each of three types of boxes, say red, green and blue. Each box has a specified value that depends on its color. The truck has a capacity of a given number of boxes. The problem is to determine how many boxes of each color to load onto the truck to maximize the total value. I will later simplify if only the maximum total value is needed.

An optimal solution can be determined with the following method.

```
def load_plan(nbr_boxes, box_value, truck_capacity)
  nbr_boxes.each_index.sort_by { |i| -box_value[i] }.
            each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |i,h|
              h[i] = [nbr_boxes[i], truck_capacity].min
              truck_capacity -= h[i]
              break(h) if truck_capacity.zero?
            end
end
```

```
nbr_boxes = [3, 1, 6]
box_value = [2, 7, 4]
truck_capacity = 6
```

```
plan = load_plan(nbr_boxes, box_value, truck_capacity)
  #=> {1=>1, 2=>5}
plan[0]
  #=> 0 
plan[1]
  #=> 1 
plan[2]
  #=> 5
```

The maximum total value is given by:

```
plan.sum { |i,n| n * box_value[i] }
  #=> 27
```

The steps are as follows.

```
a = nbr_boxes.each_index.sort_by { |i| -box_value[i] }
  #=> [1, 2, 0]
```

This shows boxes at index `1` have the greatest value and boxes at index `0` have the least value.

To illustrate the remaining calculations I will salt the code with `puts` statements.

```
a.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |i,h|
  puts "i=#{i}, h=#{h}, nbr_boxes[#{i}]=#{nbr_boxes[i]}"
  h[i] = [nbr_boxes[i], truck_capacity].min
  truck_capacity -= h[i]
  puts "  h=#{h}, truck_capacity=#{truck_capacity}"
  puts "  break #{h} as truck_capacity=0" if truck_capacity.zero? 
  break(h) if truck_capacity.zero?
end
  #=> {1=>1, 2=>5}
```

The following is displayed.

```
i=1, h={}, nbr_boxes[1]=1
  h={1=>1}, truck_capacity=5
i=2, h={1=>1}, nbr_boxes[2]=6
  h={1=>1, 2=>5}, truck_capacity=0
  break {1=>1, 2=>5} as truck_capacity=0
```

By defining the hash held by the block variable `h` as `Hash.new(0)` we can write

```
plan[0]
  #=> 0
```

even though `0` is not a key of `plan`. This uses the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes an argument and no block. The argument is called the *default value*. Often, as here, it is set to zero. All that means is that if a hash is defined `h = Hash.new(0)`, `h[k]` returns the default value (`0`) if `h` does not have a key `k`.

Note that the last statement, `break(h) if truck_capacity.zero?`, is optional. I included it merely to speed calculations.

Some simplification is possible if the optimal number of each type of box to be loaded is not needed, only the optimal total value. The following is a slight variant of the approach suggested by @engineersmnky in a comment on the question:

```
def optimal_value(nbr_boxes, box_value, truck_capacity)
  nbr_boxes.each_index.
            flat_map { |i| [box_value[i]] * nbr_boxes[i] }.
            sort.
            last(truck_capacity).sum
end
```

```
optimal_value(nbr_boxes, box_value, truck_capacity)
  #=> 27
```

Note that this works even when the truck is not full:

```
truck_capacity = 100
[2, 2, 2, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4].last(truck_capacity)
  #=> [2, 2, 2, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

---

In designing an application one might consider replacing `nbr_boxes` and `box_value` with an array of hashes such as the following.

```
boxes = [
  { name: "A", nbr: 3, value: 2 },
  { name: "B", nbr: 1, value: 7 },
  { name: "C", nbr: 6, value: 4 }
]
```

and then write:

```
def load_plan(boxes, truck_capacity)
  boxes.sort_by { |box| -box[:value] }.
        each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |box,h|
          nbr_to_load = [box[:nbr], truck_capacity].min
          h[box[:name]] = nbr_to_load
          truck_capacity -= nbr_to_load
          break(h) if truck_capacity.zero?
        end
end
```

```
plan = load_plan(boxes, truck_capacity)
  #=> {"B"=>1, "C"=>5}
plan["A"]
  #=> 0
```

The maximum total value is given by:

```
boxes.sum { |box| plan[box[:name]] * box[:value] }
  #=> 27
```

If only the maximum value is needed:

```
def optimal_value(boxes, truck_capacity)
  boxes.flat_map { |box| [box[:value]] * box[:nbr] }.
        sort.
        last(truck_capacity).
        sum
end
```

```
optimal_value(boxes, truck_capacity)
  #=> 27
```